# How do you wire a ssr relay to a arduino nano

Tags: arduino-nano, relay

I am trying to wire a fss1-102z 5v ssr relay to my arduino nano but i cant get it to work here is my circuit. It stays stuck on and i cant get it to turn off.

[image]

Bluetooth control code

```
char val;         // variable to receive data from the serial port
int ledpin = 2;  // LED connected to pin 2 (on-board LED)

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledpin = 2, OUTPUT); // pin 2 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT
  pinMode(ledpin = 3, OUTPUT); // pin 3 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT

    Serial.begin(9600);       // start serial communication at 115200bps

}

void loop()

{
  if( Serial.available() )       // if data is available to read
  {
    ;
  }
  val = Serial.read();         // read it and store it in 'val'

  if( val == 'a' )               // if 'a' was received led 2 is switched off
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 2, HIGH);    // turn Off pin 2
  }

  if( val == 'A' )               // if 'A' was received led 2 on
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 2, LOW);  // turn ON pin 2
  }

  if( val == 'b' )               // if 'b' was received led 3 is switched off
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 3, HIGH);    // turn Off pin 3
  }

  if( val == 'B' )               // if 'B' was received led 3 on
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 3, LOW);  // turn ON pin 3
  } //else (ledpin = 3, LOW)        //set led pin 3 to low state

  if( val == 'C' )               // if 'C' was received led 2 on for 1 second
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 2, LOW);  // turn ON pin 2
    delay(1000);                     // wait 1 second
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 2
  }

  if( val == 'D' )               // if 'D' was received led 3 on for 1 second
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 3, LOW);  // turn ON pin 3
    delay(1000);                     // wait 1 second
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 3
  }

  if( val == 'E' )               // if 'E' was received led 2 on for 5 seconds
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 2, LOW);  // turn ON pin 2
    delay(5000);                     // wait 500 milli seconds
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 2
  }

  if( val == 'F' )               // if 'F' was received led 3 on for 5 seconds
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 3, LOW);  // turn ON pin 3
    delay(5000);                     // wait 500 milli seconds
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);       // turn Off pin 3
  }

  if( val == 'G' )               // if 'G' was received turn led pin 2 on for 500ms then switch off and turn on pin 3 for 500 mili seconds then off
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 2, LOW);  // turn ON pin 2
    delay(500);                     // wait 500mili second
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 2
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 3, LOW);  // turn ON pin 2
    delay(500);                     // wait 500 mili second
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 2
  }

  if( val == 'h' )               // if 'h' was received switch off all pins
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 13, LOW);    // turn Off pin 13
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 2, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 2
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 3, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 3
}

  if( val == 'H' )               // if 'H' was received switch pin 2 on and off 1000 times

  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 2, HIGH);  // turn ON pin 2
   delay (1000); //wait 1000 mili seconds
    digitalWrite(ledpin = 2, LOW);  // turn Off pin 2
   delay (1000); //wait 1000 mili seconds

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its [datasheet](http://www.ateco.it/pdf/art058_fss1.pdf), the `FSS1-102Z` doesn't work with DC-voltage. Also the minimal voltage required is 50VAC. Here is the excerpt from the datasheet:

[image]

Comment: @jfpoilpret So when i hook it up to a 240v 80w pump it will work fine?

Comment: Yes, 240V AC will work with this SSR (just be careful). 80 Watts is around 0.4A, so well below the maximum 2A rating.

Comment: @jfpoilpret Should i put a diode on the input to stop current back-flow or is that only needed with coil relays?

Comment: It's Photo Isolated, so a diode isn't needed. Though I find it kind of strange that there is a coiled-relay, inside a **solid state** relay. Solid state generally means there are no moving parts. Most SSRs use triacs, I think.

Comment: so i can just wire it like in the image but to a 240v load?

Comment: Yes, the FSS1 has an input impedance of 470 Ohm, which will limit the current to 15mA max (well below the 40mA limit of the arduino). So you can just wire it directly to ground and a digital pin.

Answer (score 0):

- Is it really 5v relay?
- Need your code.
- Check your output is really 5v.

You do a lot of mistakes:

```
Int ledPin2=2;
Int ledPin3=3;
...
pinMode(ledPin2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledPin3,OUTPUT);
...
digitalWrite(ledPin2,HIGH);
```

I am on way now. I will edit and my answer when get back. Now correct your code

**EDIT**

You should improve your code... I edited it with switch cases. Also edit your comments because they are wrong!!! In the end there is `Serial.printout` states of pins. If you want uncomment them.

Here is the edited code:

```
char val;         // variable to receive data from the serial port
int ledpin2 = 2, ledpin3 = 3, ledpin13 = 13;  // LED connected to pin 2 (on-board LED)
bool status = true;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledpin2, OUTPUT); // pin 2 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT
  pinMode(ledpin3, OUTPUT); // pin 3 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT
  pinMode(ledpin13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);       // start serial communication at 115200bps

}

void loop()

{
  if( Serial.available() )       // if data is available to read
  {
  val = Serial.read();         // read it and store it in 'val'
  switch (val){
    case 'a':
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, HIGH);    // turn ON pin 2
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'A':
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, LOW);
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'b':
    digitalWrite(ledpin3, HIGH);
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'B':
    digitalWrite(ledpin3, LOW);
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'C':
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, LOW);  // turn OFF pin 2
    delay(1000);                     // wait 1 second
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, HIGH);      // turn ON pin 2
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'D':
    digitalWrite(ledpin3, LOW);  // turn OFF pin 3
    delay(1000);                     // wait 1 second
    digitalWrite(ledpin3, HIGH);      // turn ON pin 3
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'E':
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, LOW);       // turn OFF pin 2
    delay(5000);                      // wait 500 milli seconds
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, HIGH);      // turn ON pin 2
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'F':
    digitalWrite(ledpin3, LOW);  // turn ON pin 3
    delay(5000);                     // wait 500 milli seconds
    digitalWrite(ledpin3, HIGH);       // turn Off pin 3
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'G':
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, LOW);  // turn ON pin 2
    delay(500);                     // wait 500mili second
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 2
    digitalWrite(ledpin3, LOW);  // turn ON pin 2
    delay(500);                     // wait 500 mili second
    digitalWrite(ledpin3, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 2
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'h':
    digitalWrite(ledpin13, LOW);    // turn Off pin 13
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 2
    digitalWrite(ledpin3, HIGH);      // turn Off pin 3
    status = true;
    break;

    case 'H':
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, HIGH);  // turn ON pin 2
    delay (1000); //wait 1000 mili seconds
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, LOW);  // turn Off pin 2
    delay (1000); //wait 1000 mili seconds
  }
  status = true;
    break;
  }
  }

  /* Print out state of pin */
  /*
  if (status) {
   Serial.print("ledpin2 = ");
   Serial.print(bitRead(PORTD,2));
   Serial.print(" ,ledpin3 = ");
   Serial.print(bitRead(PORTD,3));
   Serial.print(" ,ledpin13 = ");
   Serial.println(bitRead(PORTD,7));
   status = false;
  }*/
}
```